# How do I use accessors to set this variable?

Tags: c#, accessor

Should I even use accessors? If not, how can I do this?

I am trying to load a texture in my game under `LoadContent()`, then trying to pass this into `Update()` so I can use it for collision detection purposes in another class.

Here is my code:

Game1.cs

```
public class GetTileType
{
    public Texture2D dirt;
    public Texture2D Dirt
    {
        get
        {
            return dirt;
        }

        set
        {
            dirt = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Main : Game
{
GetTileType getTileType = new GetTileType();

protected override void LoadContent()
{

    getTileType.Dirt = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Dirt");
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Texture2D dirt = getTileType.Dirt;

    player.GetTileType(dirt);

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Player.cs (holds collision information for now)

```
public void GetTileType(Texture2D groundTexture)
{
    Tile tile = (Tile)Main.currentLevel.GetTile(0, 0);

    Texture2D texture = tile.Texture;

    if (texture == groundTexture)
    {
        // Write code to handle what to do if the player tries to enter the ground.
    }
}
}
```

There's more in `LoadContent()`, but it's irrelevant to this problem. Same for `Update()`. In debug, `player.GetTileType(dirt);` comes up as null. It should be "Dirt" if I'm not mistaken.

I feel I am going about this all wrong, but I can't think of any other way to do it. Everything else I've tried turned into a dead-end.

When I start the game, it loads, then just hangs. I have to stop it form the task manager then.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that when you expose a field (`dirt`) through a property (`Dirt`), you should set the access of the field to 'private'.

Comment: You are using `GetTileType` as a method and as a constructor/class. That's at least weird.

Comment: getTileType.Dirt = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Dirt").Name; This doesn't look right? should you have the '.Name' at the end?

Comment: Yeah... I get lazy with naming sometimes.

Comment: @BuddhiP Sorry, that's a remnant of another trial. It's not in my code anymore. Fixed it in my post.

Comment: you should just have it like `getTileType.Dirt = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Dirt")` because the `getTileType.Dirt` is of type `Texture2D`, not the Property `Name`

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code ? You should be able to see what's going on.

Comment: I found out what's going on. The code someone gave me in another question here isn't performing as expected. I'm about to make a new question like Daniel suggested, so I'll post a link to it from here after it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are always creating new instances of `GetTileType`.

In `LoadContent` you create one instance - let's call it A - and set the `Dirt` property on that instance.
But you don't save that instance anywhere, after the method finished, A is out of scope and will eventually be garbage collected.

In `Update` you create a new instance - B - and retrieve the value of the `Dirt` property from it.
Because this is a newly created instance, this is `null`.

Comment: OK, I fixed that, but it still crashes. I hadn't realized I did that.

Comment: @SeanHeiss: What exception are you getting?

Comment: None. There are no errors, no warnings, and no exceptions after launch. It's so weird for me.

Comment: In that case, try to remove parts of the code until that behavior goes away. This will show you which part is the culprit. If you have that, come back here and post a new question. At any rate, it is out of scope of this question.

Comment: Here is a link to my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859191/whats-wrong-with-this-2d-array-initializing-code

Comment: What do you mean by saving the instance? How do I do that?

Comment: @SeanHeiss: The current code of your question is already doing that.